# How to retrieve an xml attribute from SubnodeConfiguration?

Tags: java, xml-configuration

I'm working on a class to load an XML file configuration and this class extends from XMLConfiguration.

The configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <global>
        <reloadInterval>5</reloadInterval>
    </global>

    <definitions>
        <definition>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Test name</name>
            <messages>
                <message id="1">Help menu opt 1</message>
                <message id="2">Help menu opt 2</message>
                <message id="3">Help menu opt 3</message>
            </messages>
        </definition>
    </definitions>
</root>
```

The way I'm iterating this and loading is as follows:

```
   private void updateDefinitions()
   {
      this.definitions.clear();

      List<SubnodeConfiguration> lstDefinitions = getListConfig("definitions");
      for(SubnodeConfiguration definition : lstDefinitions)
      {
         DefinitionBean aDefinition = new DefinitionBean();

         aDefinition.setId(definition.getInt("Definition.id", -1));
         aDefinition.setName(definition.getString("Definition.name", ""));

         List<MessageBean> messages = new ArrayList<MessageBean>();
         List<SubnodeConfiguration> lstMessages = definition.configurationsAt("definition.messages");
         for(SubnodeConfiguration messageBean : lstMessages)
         {
            MessageBean message = new MessageBean();

            message.setId(messageBean.getString("message"));
            messages.add(message);
         }

         definition.setMessages(messages);
         this.definitions.put(aDefinition.getId(), aDefinition);

      }
   }
```

The code is working fine, however, the problem is to get the `id` attribute for each `<message>` element, I don't know how to retrieve it. None of the getters for SubnodeConfiguration provides this, or maybe, I'm not doing it in the correct way.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I've found it. How did I found it, I've iterated through the getKeys() enumerator as follows:

    Iterator iter = messageBean.getKeys();
    Object value;
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
       value = (iter.next());
       System.out.println(value.toString());
    }
Doing this, I've noticed that to access the attribute "id", I have to do it as follows:

messageBean.getString("message[@id]")
Hope this helps if somebody is looking for it.

Fer

Answer (score 6):

I see your comment, but it's also in the [documentation here](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_xml.html#Accessing_properties_in_hierarchical_configurations). SubnodeConfiguration extends HierarchicalConfiguration.

Additionally, if you retrieve the Configuration using the method [HierarchicalConfiguration.configurationsAt()](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/HierarchicalConfiguration.html#configurationsAt%28java.lang.String%29), and the node you're retrieving, itself has attributes, you just access it with the square bracket + @ notation. For example:

Xml:

```
<foos>
  <foo bar='bazz'/>
  <foo bar='bizz'/>
  <foo bar='buzz'/>
</foos>
```

Java:

```
// load xml into config
XmlConfiguration config = ...
List<HierarchicalConfiguration> foos = config.configurationsAt("foo");
for (HierarchicalConfiguration foo : foos) {
    System.out.println(foo.getString("[@bar]"));
}
```

Should print:

```
bazz
bizz
buzz
```

Comment: If I don't know the 'foo' key's name, how can I get all the 'bar' attibute's values.

Comment: @jetma Dunno. 3.5 years is too long to recall anything for this. JavaDoc should tell you, or you can just debug and play. :-)

Comment: Just a note for anybody like me who might have automatically assumed that the intended expression engine was XPath here - it's not. If you're using the XPath engine, you'll need to omit the brackets around the attribute name.